# MS Office 2010 "color scheme" options other than Black/Blue/Silver?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

My workplace just upgraded to MS Office 2010.  For Outlook particularly, the "Black" color scheme is absolutely horrible when viewing the "folder panel" (don't know real name) in the left of the application.  See the image below.  How could anybody think these colors worked well together?  It is nearly impossible to read the number following the word "Inbox," and it is equally difficult to notice that "Deleted Items" is in bold.

[image]

I can't find anywhere to change these colors other than in `File > Options > General > Color Scheme`.  Unfortunately there are only 3 options there, and none of them are great.  Worse... if I try to choose Blue or Silver, it changes the selection for **all** Office apps... apparently it's impossible for each app to have a different scheme.

Is it possible to customize this stuff any deeper than these 3 predefined themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be the only option. Sources [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/install-themes-outlook-2010-47988.html) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-color-scheme/c4948153-db4f-46df-b023-0de7ea2d2ed3) and numerous other places.

> By default, Outlook 2010 uses a silver theme that's not stylish.
>   Although Microsoft doesn't allow you to actually install custom themes
>   in Outlook 2010, you can select one from the available themes

And it doesn't look to be any better in Outlook 2013 ([source](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-office-2013-color-theme-outlook-word/)).

Looks like it's easier to customize Outlook Web Access ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996029(v=exchg.65).aspx))

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. :-/  +1 for the answer regardless.